# How to use REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract the last string?

Tags: oracle, unix

I want to extract a last string of sentence. For example

```
input  - 'SURGICAL INC (SKUMAR) (1058585_BI_SF)'
output - 1058585_BI_SF

input  - 'MEDICAL, ABC(854567_BI_SF)'
output - 854567_BI_SF
```

How do I accomplish this using regular expressions in Oracle?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the target you want to extract?  Is the target whatever is in the last pair of parentheses?

Comment: Some details on what the input strings will always look like helps too.  Will there always be at least one pair of open/close parentheses?  Will there ever be anything following the last close parenthesis?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a regular expression you can use `'\([^(]*\)$'` - that is, an (escaped) opening parenthesis, any number of any other character, a closing parenthesis - and a $ to make it only match at the end of the string. There's a probably a neater way to make it a non-greedy match.

```
with t(input) as (
  select 'SURGICAL INC (SKUMAR) (1058585_BI_SF)' from dual
  union all select 'MEDICAL, ABC(854567_BI_SF)' from dual
)
select input, regexp_substr(input, '\([^(]*\)$') as output
from t;

INPUT                                 OUTPUT                              
------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
SURGICAL INC (SKUMAR) (1058585_BI_SF) (1058585_BI_SF)                      
MEDICAL, ABC(854567_BI_SF)            (854567_BI_SF)
```

Then you just need to remove the parentheses from that value if you don't want those. You can use nested `replace` calls, but if you're determined to stick with regular expressions, you can use `regexp_replace()` to get rid of both at once:

```
with t(input) as (
  select 'SURGICAL INC (SKUMAR) (1058585_BI_SF)' from dual
  union all select 'MEDICAL, ABC(854567_BI_SF)' from dual
)
select input,
  regexp_replace(regexp_substr(input, '\([^(]*\)$'), '[()]', null) as output
from t;

INPUT                                 OUTPUT             
------------------------------------- --------------------
SURGICAL INC (SKUMAR) (1058585_BI_SF) 1058585_BI_SF       
MEDICAL, ABC(854567_BI_SF)            854567_BI_SF
```

Regular expressions can be more expensive than simpler tools though.

Comment: How do i get rid of parenthesein Output. so my output should be - 1058585_BI_SF and 854567_BI_SF.

Comment: `replace(replace(str, ')' ,''),'(','')` ?

Answer (score 1):

do you need `regexp_substr` or using other functions will be acceptable?

for example: `reverse` - find 1st `(` after reverse - substr - reverse

```
select reverse(
  substr(reverse('SURGICAL INC (SKUMAR) (1058585_BI_SF)')
,1
,instr(reverse('SURGICAL INC (SKUMAR) (1058585_BI_SF)'), '(')
)) from dual

(1058585_BI_SF)
```

Comment: I have solve this by using INSTR and SUBSTR but using this expression become lengthy. I was looking for regular expression.

Comment: @Alex Poole provided great solution